# How to create alarm in NiFi when Data gets queued in any processors?

Tags: apache-nifi

When the data queued up between two processors in a flow and we need to be notified. the Question is how to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

We have an external job that runs every 15 minutes and monitors queues in critical NiFi processors. We use NiFi rest api to query size of queues. I.e.:

```
REQUEST_URI=$(curl -X POST "$NIFI_API/flowfile-queues/$QUEUE_ID/listing-requests" | jq '.listingRequest.uri' | tr -d '"')

echo "Request URI: $REQUEST_URI"

RESPONSE=$(curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET $REQUEST_URI)

echo "Queue response: $RESPONSE"

QUEUE_SIZE=$(echo $RESPONSE | jq '.listingRequest.queueSize.objectCount')

echo "Queue size: $QUEUE_SIZE"
```

where NIFI_API is base URL of NiFi installation followed by "nifi-api" (i.e. https://example.com/nifi-api) and QUEUE_ID is a nifi queue ID that we want to monitor. Once we have this metric in QUEUE_SIZE, we send it to our alerting\monitoring system.

For more info go to https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html and then "FlowFile Queues"